# Minimalist Style shouldn't include " - Stack Exchange" in the title

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, title, mobile-web

On the SE sites, there have always been fancy logos that fit the theme. However, the new mobile theme hides them and shows alternate text. The text has contained the site name and then " - StackExchange". I assume that this is for SEO purposes but on sites like "English Language & Usage", this gets really long and squishes up against the links.

I request that the " - Stack Exchange" text be removed from the text headers or that it be wrapped in a seperate HTML block so it is more accessible through CSS selectors".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Agree -- I am changing it so the content of the link is the shorter title without the `- Stack Exchange` part.

```
<div id="hlogo">
    <a href="/">Cooking</a>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem necessary to have the full title there, since that is always in the `<title>` tag anyway.